# Client Side JavaScript Loading Order

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have JavaScript files named: nav.js, content.js, and footer.js

My HTML page is structured like so:

```
<body>
   <div id='nav'></div>
   <div id='content'></div>
   <div id='footer'></div>
   <script src='nav.js'>
   <script src='content.js'>
   <script src='footer.js'>
</body>
```

I then use JavaScript to dynamically load the navigation bar to the nav div, same with the content and so on.

However, when the page loads, it loads the navigation bar, the footer, and then the content. Is there any way to address this problem?

Comment: Well how is it loaded? What is in the black box? My guess is you are making Ajax calls and the one just takes longer.

Comment: Not sure if it will fix your problem, but you can try using the `defer` attribute on the script you want to postpone. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

Comment: How is it loading the HTML? If there is less HTML in the footer, of course it will load first, just by nature of how network IO works... If you want it to load in order, use one script and make the loading of `content` dependent on `nav`, and `footer` dependent on `content` using Promises. We could help more if we could see the JS in those files...